# How to install third party softwares after installing ubuntu 22.04

Tags: software-installation, updates

I made a mistake. I unchecked option for installing 3rd party softwares when installing ubuntu. I followed a instruction that's says to unchecked it when doing dual-boot setup.

I did some research, some say just checked the "software restricted by copyright or legal issues (multiverse)" in software & updates and also do `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`. I don't know if this is enough, I haven't yet execute the command. Should I execute this? and there is other things should I do?

Comment: There is no harm in doing that. You can always uncheck the multiverse option and `apt remove` the restricted extras package. If you had installed 3rd party software in the meantime, that would be removed by another `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` and you would be back where you started.

Answer (score 0):

That command installs additional media codecs even a few that aren't installed with the option you mention and TTF fonts.

It's perfectly safe to run and I personally recommend doing it as one of the first post-install steps.

Please note that the TTF fonts are mostly Microsoft's (for better compatibility with files created in Microsoft Office), are freeware, but require users to accept an EULA that'll show up in terminal. In order to proceed you need to use TAB then cursor keys and enter where appropriate to accept that license.

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu Restricted Extras is an older package -- with an older MS installer (last changelog was from 2018). Installing the MS fonts manually provides you with the newer MS installer (changelog -- 2020).

It's always best to use the Third Party Software and Media Formats option with the OS installation -- since some people have had issues with the Extras package -- but if you forgot to do this, you have no other choice... just make sure that you run sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y

You may also be able to install the ubuntu-restricted-addons, libavcodec-extra, and unrar after installing the newer MS font package in order to get the extra codecs.

This will ensure that the packages are as up to date as possible. Conversely, the best way to completely -- and safely -- remove this package is by using Synaptic and check 'mark for complete removal'.